# If Statement in for loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

Im tring to get my Function to skip words in my list that arent in my string but it doesnt seem to be working

Iv tried using VBA and excel native commands... however i get the same result

```
Public Function test(range, y)

step = y

For Each cell In range

If InStr(cell, step, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

step = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(step,Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(cell, step), Len(cell), UCase(cell))

test = step
End If
Next cell

End Function
```

When I try to use this Function in Excel I get #VALUE, I suspect this is because not all the values in the list are found in the string however that the reason for the if statement

Comment: You should not use `range` as a variable name. What is the value of `y`?

Comment: Not your problem but, Use VBA's Replace: `step = Replace(step, cell, UCase(cell))` and your instr is backwards: `If InStr(step, cell, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then`

Comment: Hi There, Well Range is a list defined in Excel and y is a cell containing the string

Comment: Hi Scott, Swapped the variables and still no luck :(

Comment: Ummm...how do you have a function that doesn't set the value of "test" the function itself?  Doesn't that guarantee that the value of the function will be #VALUE ?   If you just want to run the replace, not return a value, I'm not sure this should be a function.

Comment: Hi Roy, So if I Remove the If statement and ensure that all the words in the lists exist in the Strings it works perfectly. However, in the real-world application, there would be cases where some words are not in a specific string and would need to be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have the variable backwards in the Instr.  and you must use the firs criterion if you use the last.

Also if you are looking for complete words then you need to use `" "` on the search and replace.

Lastly use vba's Replace:

```
Public Function test(rng As range, y As String)
    Dim step As String
    step = y

    Dim cell As range
    For Each cell In rng
        If InStr(1, " " & step & " ", " " & cell & " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            step = Replace(" " & step & " ", " " & cell & " ", UCase(" " & cell & " "))
        End If
    Next cell

    test = Application.Trim(step)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks so much! Worked like a Charm. I'm new to using VBA with Excel. I'll take my time to understand and learn for this. Thank you! :)